# Change the vertical spacing of one legend in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting two sets of data in ggplot2 with code like the following, which leads to me having two legends (ignore the ugly plot, this is just an example)

```
x <- ggplot(mtcars)+
  theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position=c(0.8, 0.8), legend.direction="horizontal", 
          legend.key.size=unit(0.008, "cm"), legend.title=element_blank(), 
          legend.margin=margin(), legend.spacing = unit(0.04, "cm")) +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6)), shape= guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5))) +
    geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=cyl, colour=cyl))+
    geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y = hp, shape=as.factor(carb)))

print(x)
```

[image: ot]

The issue is that for me, the black shapes in the bottom are vertically too close together, I would like the two rows of black shapes to have more vertical space between them. I tried to use legend.spacing.y but it did not help at all, it only changed the space between the two individual legends (for cyl and carb). I would like to know if there's some theme command that would let me do something like legend.spacing(legend=carb, unit(0.1, "cm")) so it specifically acts on the carb legend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `keyheight` argument in `guide_legend`

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8),
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.key.size = unit(0.008, "cm"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.margin = margin(),
    legend.spacing = unit(0.04, "cm")
  ) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 6)),
         shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5), keyheight = 2)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, colour = cyl)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp, shape = as.factor(carb)))
```

[image]